# Azure APIM inbound policy ignore case for the property name

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, inbound

I have inbound policy as below

```
<choose>
 <when condition="@((context.Request.Body != null) && context.Request.Body.As<JObject> 
   (preserveContent: true)["ChannelID"] != null)">
   <set-header name="channelId" exists-action="override">
    <value>"@(context.Request.Body.As&amp;amp;amp;lt;JObject&amp;amp;amp;gt;(preserveContent: true) 
    ["ChannelID"])"</value>
   </set-header>
 </when>
</choose>
```

But the inboundpolicy treating the ChannelID as case sensitive.In the request body if we pass as channelId then ChannelID property is not getting recognized.

**How can we make the property name as case insensitive in the inbound policy?**

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.Since it is a JObject, we can add case ignore as follow.

```
<choose>
<when condition="@((context.Request.Body != null) && context.Request.Body.As<JObject>(preserveContent: true).GetValue("channelId", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)?.Value<string>() != null)">
    <set-header name="channelId" exists-action="override">
        <value>@(context.Request.Body.As<JObject>(preserveContent: true).GetValue("channelId", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)?.Value<string>())</value>
    </set-header>
</when>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `check-header` policy to enforce that a request has a specified HTTP header.

```
<check-header name="header name" failed-check-httpcode="code" failed-check-error-message="message" ignore-case="true">
    <value>Value1</value>
    <value>Value2</value>
</check-header>
```

`ignore-case` : Can be set to `True` or `False`. **If set to True case is ignored when the header value is compared against the set of acceptable values.**

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#CheckHTTPHeader).

Comment: I wanted to check the body property. not the header. I have to read the body property and set a new header based on that value to support a old client API.  But i am not sure while reading the body property how to ignore the case, because user might give capital or small names(Ex: ChannelId : 10/channelId :10 /channelID : 10)